# Como instalar un Certificado SSL en Bitnami/Apache

Tags: django, apache, certificado-ssl

un gusto poder saludarles.

Quisiera por favor pudieran ayudarme con la implementación de un certificado SSL dentro de bitnami/apache

Para hacer corto el cuento, tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Django + bitnami/apache

A continuación es dejo como está la estructura del bitnami/apache

Certificados SSL
server cer
server key
server crt

Están dentro de la ubicación : /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/
La configuración del bitnami-ssl conf es la siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.cer"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
</VirtualHost>
```

y el httpd-ssl conf esta de la siguiente manera:

```
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
SSLCACertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
```

Si pudieran orientarme de la mejor manera, se los agradecería.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Has intentado reiniciando apache? Cada cambio que hagas requiere de un reinicio para tomar efecto.

Comment: Claro lo he hecho pero sigue sin resultar

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Si no indicas en tu pregunta cómo está configurado Apache para usar los certificados, es imposible dar una respuesta concreta. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade el contenido de los archivos de configuración que sea relevante a la pregunta. (sin incluir contraseñas u otros datos sensibles, por favor)

Comment: Listo @Alfabravo muchas gracias por tus correciones